# Multiple categorical IVs and DVs with 3/5 levels prediction model

Tags: modeling, interpretation, prediction, many-categories

**I have a data-set with 
8 categorical IVs with 2/3 levels (one level for one type of conditions), 
2 categorical DVs with 3/5 levels (one level for one type of responses:dis/even/ad). 
Participants were tested repeatedly. 
I am looking for a best model in R for prediction.**

So far, the most relative approach I've found online is multinomial-logistic-multilevel-models-in-r, and I used 'brms' package:

############### model for all 6 effects

`brm2.1 <-brm(allocation~age_group+gender+country+competition+relation+cost)+(1|id),data=R2long,family=categorical)`

I managed to get some outputs like the following:

############### summary(brm2.1)

[image]

############### I also ploted the model:

`plot(brm2.1,N = 5)`

[image: output and tables from software]

Multinomial-logistic-multilevel-models is new to me so I don't know how to interpret the summary outputs, i'd like to know information like:

- 1: how to find the best fitted model? 
  I did modelling for 'glmer' and i wonder if that's the same way, like top down bottom?
- 2: how to explain the effects of each IV and interactions? like the effect size, significance,  affect the whole model, etc.
- 3: how to find the predicted percentages? like how many people may respond in 1 of the 3 ways to certain manipulation?
- 4: what does the plot mean?? i never see plot like this before.....

I know that're a lot questions, i am really grateful any help.

Comment: We really do need more context to answer this. What is yor response variable? continuous? categorical? What does it measure? Same question for your independent variables! How many observations ...

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! All my variables (both IVs and DVs) are all categorical with more than 2 levels, and I have 200 observations. I think i should run multinomial-logistic-multilevel-models-in-r(this is the most relative approach I found online), and i used 'brms' package to try that but I can't really understand the outputs! please help!

Comment: Please add that new information as an edit to your Q (few people read comments). Also include some of the output you do not understand, and detail what you understand, what not

Comment: hi, I've re-edited my Q, please have a look if you can...thanks so much for helping

Comment: Just looking at your point 4, you fit a Bayesian model, and I believe those are Bayesian diagnostic graphs. If you weren't aware that you fit a Bayesian model, and you don't know how to do Bayesian diagnostics, it may be worth using a different package. Also, you said that you have two categorical dependent variables. Can you clarify if they are ordered categorical, or un-ordered categorical?

Comment: Hi Weiwen, Thanks for replying, i don't mind changing the package but so far brms is the best i can find online for running a multinomial logistic multilevel models in R with multilevel categorical DVs. Two Dvs are both un-ordered categorical variables. I 'd like plots which can show me the predicted probabilities rather than diagnostics(what even does this mean????) I have check the CRAN file of brms and i think i did the right model, but i can't interpret the outputs...so help please

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you used a Bayesian package, perhaps without specifically knowing that it was a Bayesian package. I'm not very familiar with Bayesian analysis, and with no offense intended, it appears you are not either. So it would probably be better to switch to a different package. I'm not familiar with R packages, but the UCLA stats webpage offers a [worked example](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/) of multinomial regression with the `nnet` package.

In your question, you fit a model for the multinomial regression to the dependent variable *allocation*, which takes the levels dis, even, and ad. Here, the package chose **ad** as the base level. You got two sets of coefficients representing the effect of a unit change in each variable on the log odds (or something) of choosing that category versus the base category. I said "or something" because you appear to have applied an identity link, which is not the default in real multinomial regression (but I guess you can do this in a GLM). Identity link implies that your coefficients are on the probability scale, but that doesn't really look possible given some of the coefficients (e.g. some are over 1), so I have no idea what scale the output is on. So much for answering your question 2. Whatever the package you use, your output is going to come in a similar format because that's what multinomial regression does.

Question 4: those are diagnostic plots. Real Bayesians, please forgive me if I mangle this, but my understanding is that in Bayesian estimation, you are essentially simulating what the parameter values of interest could be. The plots on the right are a trace of the parameter values in each simulation. You basically want the estimation algorithm to wander randomly over the parameter space close to whatever the Bayesian equivalent of the MLE estimate is. It appears that those 5 plots meet that criterion, but you only asked `brms` to plot 5 parameters. I believe the plots on the left are the posterior distribution of the parameter. You want these to look approximately normal. The ones you presented do. These are just model diagnostics you should perform. If you have no idea what any of this means, then (as mentioned earlier) switch packages. That sort of takes care of your Q4.

For your Q1, you only fit one model, so there's no best fit model. In Bayesian estimation, there are parallels to the information criteria we typically use in frequentist maximum likelihood estimation.

I've never used that package, so I haven't even attempted to answer Q3.

Comment: Thanks so much Weiwen Ng! That's very informative, I've also found other material on brms, like [https://xcelab.net/rm/statistical-rethinking/] so  I think i will need time to get through this cuz you are right, this is my first time come cross with Bayesians.